# Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91) in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Getting error: Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91) in excel vba.

```
    Sub RegisterNewUser()

'Disable screen refresh during code excution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Variables
Dim users As Worksheet           'Variable for users table sheet
Dim NewUser As Worksheet         'Variable for new user entry sheet
Dim RecordIsValid As String
Dim NextRecordIndex As Long      'Variable for the next available row in the users table

Set users = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("USERS")
Set NewUser = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW USER")
NextRecordIndex = users.ListObjects("USERS").ListRows.Count

If NextRecordIndex = 0 Then

users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex, 1).Value = NewUser.Range("D" & 6).Value

Else

NextRecordIndex = NextRecordIndex + 1

users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex, 1).Value = NewUser.Range("D" & 6).Value

    End If
```

Error is exactly here:

```
after the if statement:
```

users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex, 1).Value = NewUser.Range("D" & 6).Value

The code in the else condition is working fine. It only gives this error if the USERS table is empty and the row count is zero.

Can anyone please guide what is the problem?

Thanks..

Comment: So on the USERS worksheet, you have a table called USERS?

Comment: Check if ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW USER") evaluates to Nothing

Comment: Yes there is a USERS table under USERS worksheet.

Comment: The code in else condition is working fine:

NextRecordIndex = NextRecordIndex + 1

users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex, 1).Value = NewUser.Range("D" & 6).Value

It only doesn't work if NextRecordIndex is 0 (Table is empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number or records is 0, you can't refer to:

`users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange`

Because it does not exist (`DataBodyRange = Nothing`)

You should add an empty row first:

`users.ListObjects("USERS").ListRows.Add`

You should also replace:

```
users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex, 1).Value
```

with

```
users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex+1, 1).Value
```

**EDIT:**

The `if` statement is probably redundant, the following code should work in every case:

```
NextRecordIndex = users.ListObjects("USERS").ListRows.Count

users.ListObjects("USERS").ListRows.Add
users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(NextRecordIndex + 1, 1).Value = 
      NewUser.Range("D" & 6).Value
```

Comment: Nice hint. error is gone but the records got inserted in the header row.
Any way to insert in the first table row when table is empty?

Comment: @SupermanAkrt Please take a look at the second part of the answer (edit). Simply add `1` to `NextRecordIndex`.

Comment: Great, working now but I have a question:

When I user: users.ListObjects("USERS").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value
It added in the 2nd DataBodyRange row.

Comment: @SupermanAkrt I have edited my answer once again to simplify your code.